# Dealing with white space in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an xml `lists.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data>
  <list>
    <item>Salt</item>
    <item>Sugar</item>
  </list>
  <list>
    <item>Eggs</item>
    <item>Butter</item>
  </list>
</data>
```

and an XSLT stylesheet `transform.xslt`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="3.0">
  <xsl:output method="text"/>
  <xsl:template match="//list/item">
    <xsl:text> - </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="." />
    <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text><!--put a line-break between two list points--->
    <xsl:if test="position() = last()"><!--put another line-break at the end of a list-->
      <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

My expected output is something like the following:

```
 - Salt    
 - Sugar

 - Eggs
 - Butter
```

but instead I get the above with way to much output when trasforming using saxon (or other processors). So how do I deal white-space properly in XSLT?

Note: I'm completely new to XSLT and I am aware that my code posted above might be bad – so, beside the question, I appreciate any suggestions to make it more elegant/better to read/faster/shorter...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply add `<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>` to stylesheet.

Answer (score 2):

Besides using `<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>`, another way to control whether those whitespace-only `text()` nodes are included in your output is to use an empty template matching on `text()` who's value do not have any "meaningful" text.

In the example below, using `normalize-space()` to collapse any whitespace characters (space, tab, carriage return), and then negate that value in a predicate. The advantage of this approach is that you could always customize this template to include/exclude certain `text()` nodes and not make it a global/binary decision.

Also, for your template match expression, you don't need the descendant `//`. The match pattern can just be `list/item` to match any `item` that is a child of `list`.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="3.0">
  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:template match="text()[not(normalize-space())]"/>

  <xsl:template match="list/item">
    <xsl:text> - </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="." />
    <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text><!--put a line-break between two list points-->
    <xsl:if test="not(following-sibling::item)"><!--put another line-break at the end of a list-->
        <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: thanks for your tips... The Problem with your solution for me is that it seems to have the side effect of deleting the additional line break at the end of a list...

Comment: whoops, didn't pay close enough attention to realize that the extra line break was for each set of list items. Updated